# Is it possible to mock classes that only expose Factory constructors?

Tags: mocking, dart

Recently I had a need to mock the Timer class in test. This turned out to be an issue because Timer doesnt have any public default constructors because it uses all factory constructors. Is it possible to mock classes that dont have a public default constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Dart class has an implicit interface. You can just `implement Timer` and mock the class this way.

Comment: In the case of Timer the constructor is part of the API as creating a new Timer starts it immediately. Personally I think the API is kinda awkward, doing work in the constructor usually is, so I am now using a wrapper around Timer that has a start method.

Comment: That sounds like a useful class. I usually do a similar thing to abstract DateTime.now(), but that can just be a function.